# Android Google Maps into a v4 Fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a fragment with a google maps, it works without problems.
Today I change the Fragment to a v4 Fragment.
I changed the MapFragment into the xml with a SupportMapFragment and into the java I changed the code with a `googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

After these changes I have a gray screen into the maps with this logcat:

```
The Google Play services  resources www not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

And then:

```
Authorization failure. Please see http... for how to correctly set up the map. ....
```

And...

```
Failded to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue.
```

Before the fragment's change it works without any problem.

Thanks.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6048. reference google play services properly. Have the right api key

Comment: Google Play and the key is right. Before the Fragment's change it works perfectly.